# How do I connect an AWS EC2 Windows Instance to a Simple AD Domain in another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Simple AD addresses are private and cannot be made public and is [not a recommended practice](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=683326).

I wanted a simple way to add a new Windows Machine in any region I choose but to be able to use a single Simple AD domain for all machines.

Proposed solutions include using workspaces to assign public IP addresses, or VPCs using public Internet Gateways and IPSec Tunnels.

I think what I need something that should not need an network engineering degree but I'm having trouble figuring this one out.

[This](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=73068) 6 year old thread suggests an Amazon article that ends by saying:

> AWS highly recommends leveraging virtual network appliances available
>   in the AWS Marketplace to significantly reduce the level of effort to
>   establish and maintain these VPN connections. This design will result
>   in additional EC2 and, potentially, third-party license charges. [...]

Is there a simple answer to my question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple answer unfortunately. If you want a private connection into AWS I believe your most likely option would be creating a VPN tunnel between the two regions VPCs.

VPC Peering would be the easiest option, but you cannot use VPC Peering across regions without the use of a VPN (https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-multiple-region-multi-vpc-connectivity/).

In regards to the article found there is OpenVPN that you can download and install onto an EC2 instance to facilitate this access (https://docs.openvpn.net/how-to-tutorialsguides/virtual-platforms/amazon-ec2-appliance-ami-quick-start-guide/).

Hope you've managed to complete this easier already!